# how to write the query command in mysql

Tags: mysql

table `categories`（TABLE_CATEGORIES） ,which have fields:  `categories_id` ,`parent_id`

table `categories_description`（TABLE_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION） which have fields: `categories_id`, `categories_name`,

now, according to `$cpath=parent_id` I want to get the `categories_name` and `categories_id` , this is my command,but it shows a grammar error.

```
$query = "select c.categories_id, cd.categories_name from " .
TABLE_CATEGORIES . " c, " . TABLE_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION . " cd
                          where c.categories_id=cd.categories_id and c.parent_id=".$cPath;
```

the error:1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2

Comment: Can you tell us what error you're getting?

Comment: And what is the value of $query after interpolation?

Comment: If you don't post your $query value before sending it to db, we cannot help you more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
SELECT cd.categories_id, cd.categories_name
FROM `TABLE_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION` cd 
    INNER JOIN `TABLE_CATEGORIES` c
    ON cd.categories_id = c.categories_id
WHERE c.parent_id = your_id
```

**EDITED to reflect modified user question:**
Are you sure that both "TABLE_CATEGORIES" and "TABLE_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION" don't contain white spaces or strange chars?
If so you must enclose them with backticks.

Comment: There's no difference in your query? (other than implicit vs explicit join, and better formatted)

Comment: @Marcus: Well, I think that using `JOIN` is better than using `WHERE` (even if some engine convert it when it realizes what query should do); anyway OP didn't give us anything else to work with ;)

Comment: I totally agree with that, just questioning that it wouldn't solve the problem ;)

Comment: @runeveryday: take a look at my edited post

Comment: @Marcus: I saw OP posted the error and I edited my post. Do you think that could be the problem?

Comment: Probably not. My guess is that $cPath is empty. If there was a problem with the table-names it would generate more info in the error. And also `table categories（TABLE_CATEGORIES)` I think refers to that the table name is categories.

Comment: @Marcus: don't know, the error tells _use near '' at line 2_, but if OP doesn't post the query he's running, IMO we can only _imagine_ what's happening. Anyway your point is right, a possible error could be an empty $cPath or wrong type...

Comment: Usually the error returns the first character after the error followed by some more of the query. I base my assumption on that this returns an empty string and since $cpath is in the end there's nothing more to return. Anyway, all is, as you say, assumptions until OP provides more info :)

Comment: @Marcus: maybe I was right in some of my considerations... but we'll never know which one :D

Answer (score 0):

Inner join may help...

SELECT c.categories_id,  cd.categories_name
FROM TABLE_CATEGORIES c
INNER JOIN TABLE_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION cd ON c.categories_id=cd.categories_id  where c.parent_id=$cPath

Please check this code also :

$query = "select c.categories_id, cd.categories_name from " . TABLE_CATEGORIES . " c, " . TABLE_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION . " cd where c.categories_id=cd.categories_id and c.parent_id='".$cPath."'";

Comment: It's actually performing an inner join already. It's called an implicit join.